# how to transfer rig from one model to another?

Tags: rigging, auto-rig-pro

I have a rig on a model thats skinned, and I have another model not similar that I wanted to take that rig and transfer from the skinned model and connect it to the unskinned model.

As does Script AutoBiped (Remplace Mixiamo Rig with Biped Rig)

How can I do that automatically, any script or method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it automatically in vanilla blender, not that I know of. I recommend copying and pasting it, then parenting the mesh to the rig. That's not too long to do and you don't have to search for any scripts